# So I have changed my script to find the product of two numbers in succession to each other below users maxvalue now this happens

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So this script is supposed to allow a user to enter a maximum value that they wish to find all the numbers who are the product of two numbers in succession to each other less than or equal to the maximum value. What ends up happening is it mostly works but seems to go one number over the maximum value instead of stopping at or before the maximum value and I am not sure why it is behaving that way. Any help is appreciated. Below are the code and output of two different maximum values I tried.

Code

```
#!/bin/bash
#Task 3.
#This part allows the user to set the range of numbers they wish to find the products of two nonnegative number in succession to each other
count=0
echo "Input a maximum value."

read -r maxval
count=1
val1=0
val2=1
term=$((val1*val2))

echo "Ok all the products of two numbers in succession to each smaller than or equal to $maxval are as follows."

while [ "$term" -le "$maxval" ]
do
        term=$(($val1*$val2))
        echo "$term"
        ((val1++))
        ((val2++))
        ((count++))

done

echo "You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other smaller than or equal to $maxval."
echo "The total amount of products found in your range of products with integers in succesion to each other was $count"
```

Output 1

```
Input a maximum value.
13
Ok all the products of two numbers in succession to each smaller than or equal to 13 are as follows.
0
2
6
12
20
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other smaller than or equal to 13.
The total amount of products found in your range of products with integers in succesion to each other was 6
```

Output 2

```
Input a maximum value.
154
Ok all the products of two numbers in succession to each smaller than or equal to 154 are as follows.
0
2
6
12
20
30
42
56
72
90
110
132
156
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other smaller than or equal to 154.
The total amount of products found in your range of products with integers in succesion to each other was 14
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gist of the problem is that `term` is being calculated (and printed) **after** the test; you want to switch it around so that you calculate **before** the test.

One idea:

```
while [ "$term" -le "$maxval" ]       # if we pass the test ...
do
        echo "$term"                  # dislplay and ...
        ((val1++))
        ((val2++))
        ((count++))                   # optimistically +1 assuming next test is successful and ...
        term=$(($val1*$val2))         # calculate for the next test
done

((count--))                           # last test was unsuccessful so -1
```

Test runs:

```
$ ./count.bash
Input a maximum value.
13
Ok all the products of two numbers in succession to each smaller than or equal to 13 are as follows.
0
2
6
12
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other smaller than or equal to 13.
The total amount of products found in your range of products with integers in succesion to each other was 4

$ ./count.bash
Input a maximum value.
154
Ok all the products of two numbers in succession to each smaller than or equal to 154 are as follows.
0
2
6
12
20
30
42
56
72
90
110
132
You have now reached the end of your range of products with integers in succession to each other smaller than or equal to 154.
The total amount of products found in your range of products with integers in succesion to each other was 12
```